# Why my remote login to MongoDB succeeded, but I can't use command 'show collections'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, shell

When I remote login mongodb I will see it's successed, but when I use command "use databasename" 
"show collections"

you will see this.
it's wrong on remote client

```
root@c148ad06550e:/# mongo --host 192.168.1.202 -uroot -proot --authenticationDatabase admin
> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13
> connecting to: 192.168.1.202:27017/test
> Server has startup warnings: 
> 2017-06-01T16:53:00.807+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING:
> You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-06-01T16:53:00.807+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
2017-08-17T19:45:01.817+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: cmdResult.cursor is undefined :
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:692:5
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:776:16
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:785:19
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:796:16
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:754:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:651:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
> db.users.find()
> show users
{
"_id" : "admin.root",
"user" : "root",
"db" : "admin",
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "root",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
] }
```

but it is normally at the host 192.168.1.202,like this

```
root@debian:/usr/local/mongodb2.8/bin# ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.8.0-rc0
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2017-06-01T16:53:00.807+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-06-01T16:53:00.807+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
system.indexes
system.users
system.version
> db.system.users.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : "admin.root",
"user" : "root",
"db" : "admin",
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : 10000,
        "salt" : "Q1akyPuUo6BC8xXhw9pBdQ==",
        "storedKey" : "42jx7vHOdT9nTsLQZwdG5Y3w8ec=",
        "serverKey" : "4rY/clpyRlOT1k7SiS6BXaPdO2I="
    }
},
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "root",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
]}
{
"_id" : "empery.root",
"user" : "root",
"db" : "empery",
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : 10000,
        "salt" : "khy2VzPyHAFKB5UuN6eqCw==",
        "storedKey" : "uBK5llUXKVtporbNFQOyVqI+qTU=",
        "serverKey" : "MdFETK/LSmNH3ItMJiLsuIaTiIc="
    }
},
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "empery"
    }
]}
> show users
{
"_id" : "admin.root",
"user" : "root",
"db" : "admin",
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "root",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
]}
```

I see the mongodb version is not same in client and server,
3.2 and 2.8.

Anybody can tell me why?

Comment: MongoDB 2.8.0-rc0 is the first release candidate for what eventually became the MongoDB 3.0 production release. I would upgrade to a stable/production release rather than trying to troubleshoot a historical release candidate. As per the startup warning in your output, it is also not recommended to run `mongod` as the `root` user. In the `mongo` shell you  can check the version of your `mongo` shell with `version()` and the version of the remote server you are connected to with `db.version()`.

Comment: @Stennie   ok,thanks